# Ground-level Free-Standing Deck Frame (Feedback Requested)

Tags: framing, deck, load-bearing

I would like to ask for your feedback on the deck frame illustrated in the image below. It is a ground-level, free-standing deck.

All your feedback is highly appreciated!

### Iteration 1

[image: Frame]

[Edit]
**

### Iteration 2

[image]

**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this [residential wood deck construction guide](https://www.awc.org/pdf/codes-standards/publications/dca/AWC-DCA62009-DeckGuide-1007.pdf).

Looks like 2x6 joist lumber is not an option per IRC, and for 8' joist span your 8' beam would need to be 2-2x10s minimum (or other options depending on wood species).

*IRC deck framing guide courtesy of prior question by @psaxton*

Comment: Seems to me that the guide as shown doesn't cover such a small deck. I would not conclude from this guide that 2x6 joist lumber is inadequate for these dimensions.

Comment: The beam is only spanning a couple feet at a stretch, so that's not a concern. 8' joists should be at least 2x8 in my opinion. Except for stair landings, 2x6 is not suitable for joists. They'll be too bouncy.

Comment: @isherwood, (1) If I add blockings between the 2x6 joists, would that mitigate the problem? (e.g. http://www.african-cichlid.com/blocking.jpg) 
(2) Given that 2x6s aren't suitable for for joists and they should be upgraded to 2x8s, I believe I must change the beams as well to double 2x8. Right?

Comment: Your decking already acts as blocking between the joists to distribute load. I still don't consider it enough. Ideally, flush beams are the same height as the joists (or larger). If you did that you could eliminate one support block.

Comment: Thanks @isherwood! I've updated the question post by adding a second iteration of the design based on your comments. All beams / joists are upgraded to 2x8s. Two piers are removed. Does this look good to you? 
Also, about joist spacing, should I go with 12'' o.c. or 16'' per iteration 2?

Comment: Good on the increase to 8x, and yes the beam needs to be at least the same dimension as the joist if you are using joist hangers.

Comment: By "laminated" beam do you mean a special beam or just two 2x8's nailed together. Laminated beams are not resistant to decay or termites so I think you would want to use PT 2x lumber.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it, that rule isn't hard-and-fast. Plenty of joists (or engineered trusses) are top-hang or use hangers that only attach at the top. This could apply to decks (with solid lumber) as well with the right hangers.

Comment: @isherwood, agreed. The code has allowances for alternate methods and materials per local AHJ, and surely there are limitless engineering solutions, **but**; with the materials and methods described in the question, and assuming when the OP says he will use "joist hangers" he means the typical type, *the code is specific*: the beam depth must be at least equal to the joist depth.

Answer (score 1):

The challenge here is to do the minimum that will work, but not less than the minimum. One incremental change I can see would be to sister an additional 2x6 (maybe 2x8) in the middle third of each joist. This would reduce deflection in the middle.

Even better to prevent downward deflection would be to use long metal strapping on the underside of each 2x6 joist, extending over the middle 1/3 (2/3?) of each joist. This would be either flat or angle. The underside of each joist is under tension when loaded down and a metal strap nailed with multiple nails along its length would resist deformation with little increase in weight.

Real designers could surely come up with a truly minimalist design that would use half the wood that an amateur would think was necessary. For example, I'll bet trusses out of PT 2x2 lumber would work. There are youtube videos showing how to make a set of identical trusses. Gusset plates would be from PT plywood, waterproof glued, and nailed with stainless steel nails or just deck screws.

Comment: Metal strapping will not significantly change the joist's tendency to bounce. The stretch that occurs when a joists flexes a quarter inch is almost immeasurably small (some of the longitudinal movement is compression), and you won't get that type of tension with typical assembly done by hand with common components. There will be movement in the fasteners, for example, which completely negates any benefit.

Comment: The problem with the 2x2 truss idea is that one single failure point takes the whole system down. Unless you're using engineered (laminated) 2x2, there will be many weak points. Gussets would need to be carefully fastened to not introduce weakness as well, and twist would be largely uncontrolled. Basically, framing is done like it is due to the very nature of wood and the inability of a field carpenter to work to a high enough level of precision.

Comment: @isherwood, what do you think of the idea of sistering additional 2x6 in the middle third? Would this significantly stiffen the joists? Would it concentrate stress at the points where the the sistered piece ends? Remember how old wooden ladders had the metal rod supports under the treads? In the case of a shed weight is not a consideration.

Comment: I do remember the ladders, but that was for total strength, not stiffness. Those rungs are only about 20 inches wide and had substantial flex. Sistering just the center third probably wouldn't do the job, either. I think you'd need to connect the ends of any reinforcement within about 10% of each end to dramatically improve stiffness.

Answer (score 1):

I think your second iteration is workable. I'm not sure 2x8 joists would meet code, but I believe that they'd be appropriately strong and rigid. For an 8x8 deck at that height I think that's exactly what I'd do, except I'd go 16" centers. The extra joists and decking fasteners probably aren't going to provide any real benefit (unless you expect to have more than a few people on the deck at once or will be setting a hot tub on it).

<sub>$.02 successfully registered.</sub>

Comment: I think you mean 2x8 joists *would* meet the code. Right?

Comment: Not in my experience, but it depends on the jurisdiction.

Answer (score 1):

My instinct is that 2x8's on 16 in centers for the joists should be fine. I would probably use 2x10's for the beams. I would put a row of staggered blocking down the middle of the joists. Don't forget to put the crown UP on all the lumber. After all that, you could probably drive a car on it.

Comment: Great ideas, thanks @BrianK! About the crown, is there a good way to identify it other than trying to visually spot the higher edge? I spent some good time trying to do so and sometimes I couldn't really determine the crown side for some boards. (I'm pretty much beginner to woodworking).

Comment: Practice makes perfect for identifying crown. Hold one end of the board up, sight down the narrow edge and see what you think. Flip it over and sight the other narrow edge. You'll figure it out. Some boards have very little crown. And if you really want to check your work, use a chalkline/string beside the edge -- it'll be obvious in the middle.